# How to add post_author column to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, wp-admin, admin

I've created a custom post type with this code:

```
register_post_type(
    'custom_type',
    array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'description'         => '',
        'public'              => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_icon'           => $icon,
        'can_export'          => false,
        'delete_with_user'    => false,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'query_var'           => false,
        'capability_type'     => 'custom_type',
        'map_meta_cap'        => true,
        'rewrite'             => false,
        'supports'            => array(
            'title',
            'custom-fields'
        )
    )
);
```

However, I cannot find the `post_author` shown on the `edit.php`, what wrong with this code?

Comment: Have you checked, if the "author" checkbox is selected in the view options in the top right corner?

Answer (score 7):

The `$supports` argument should include `author` for the Author settings to be available for the custom post type:

```
'supports' => array(
    'title',
    'custom-fields',
    'author'
)
```

> **'supports'** (array) Core feature(s) the post type supports. Serves as an alias for calling add_post_type_support() directly. Core
>   features include 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'revisions',
>   'trackbacks', 'author', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail',
>   'custom-fields', and 'post-formats'. Additionally, the 'revisions'
>   feature dictates whether the post type will store revisions, and the
>   'comments' feature dictates whether the comments count will show on
>   the edit screen. Defaults is an array containing 'title' and 'editor'.

Docs for [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)

Comment: Thanks. Can I know what exactly `author` supported added to my content type? Since I am using the `post_author` anyway and no issue with that, but  I don't want any hidden surprise if I enable it...

Comment: Not sure I understand your question 100%, but adding support for `author` will make the Author column available in the post type listing in the admin and will make the author meta box appear when editing the post.